# Utilizar um Criteria NOT com o Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Atualmente, eu tenho uma pesquisa com Criteria que me traz resultados normalmente, mas quero adicionar nela uma implementação do tipo `NOT`.

Alguém tem uma ideia de como eu  poderia de como fazer isso?

Coloquei no código um comentário com uma possível ideia da implementação, mas não obtive exito.

Segue a parte do código:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
public List<ContaCorrenteModel> findByContaClieAssinat(Short banco, Short agencia, Long conta) {

    List<ContaCorrenteModel> ccModel;



public List<ContaCorrenteModel> findByContaClieAssinat(Short banco, Short agencia, Long conta) {

    List<ContaCorrenteModel> ccModel;



ArquivoLog.escreverLog
("Iniciando consulta [ClienteDaoImpl] findByContaClieAssinat - Parametros utilizados:"
 + " Banco " + banco +" Agencia " + agencia + " Conta " + conta );
    this.session = ConexaoHibert.getInstance();

    switch (Principal.getBase()) {
    case CENTRAL:
        List<TbCntaCrrtClie> tbCntaCrrtClieList = new ArrayList<TbCntaCrrtClie>();


        Criteria crit = this.session.createCriteria(TbCntaCrrtClie.class, "conta");

        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("conta.cdBanc", banco));
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("conta.cdAgen", agencia));

   // Restricao que tenho que Adicionar a consulta criteria //
   crit.add(Restrictions.not("conta.nrOrdeTitl", new Long(2) ));

        crit.setFetchMode("nrSequPessUnic", FetchMode.JOIN);
        crit.setFetchMode("tbPenumUnic.nrSequClieFirmPodr", FetchMode.JOIN);
        crit.setFetchMode("tbPenumUnic.tbRpreGrupCollection", FetchMode.JOIN);
        crit.setFetchMode("nrSequNatzCnta", FetchMode.JOIN);



        tbCntaCrrtClieList = crit.list();

        ArquivoLog.escreverLog("Total de clientes CENTRAL: " + tbCntaCrrtClieList.size());

        ccModel =  ContaCorrenteModelAdapter.adapt(tbCntaCrrtClieList);
        break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar isso:

```
crit.add(Restrictions.ne("conta.nrOrdeTitl", 2L));
```

O nome do método `ne` significa *not equals*, ou seja, é o oposto do `eq` que significa *equals*.

Ah, e não use coisas como `new Integer` e `new Long`. São desnecessárias vez que o autoboxing já faz isso para você com a vantagem de ainda manter cache de alguns valores. Inclusive, no Java 9, esses construtores das classes empacotadoras foram marcados com `@Deprecated` por essa razão.